# Whenever I launch Ubuntu my screen of PC starts flashing continuously

Tags: screen, flicker

Hi I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my HP desktop PC and it’s dual boot with windows 10. Windows 10 runs fine but whenever I launch Ubuntu my screen of PC starts flashing continuously and it’s very difficult to use I can still use it but it’s really difficult plz help.

```
My system info : PC : hp desktop
                 Processor : Intel petinum(R) GPU G620 @2.60GHz x 2
                 Graphics : Intel HD Graphics 2000 (SNB GT1)
                 OS name : Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
                 OS type : 64-bit
                 GNOME Version : 3.36.2
                 Windowing System : X11
                 Memory : 3.8 GiB
                 Disk space : 1.0 TB
```

[Video on the error while using live usb same happens using normal installation](https://vimeo.com/429213063)

Comment: Go to Settings, Displays, and try and select a different resolution for the display. Also, show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact model # of your computer.

Comment: Yea thanks for that but I’m trying to install a older version and I deleted the previous one if it does not resolve I will surely send

Comment: If you send me the BIOS version, and the model #, I can at least check if there's a newer version available for you.

Comment: Ok will do in a few hours

Comment: Hey I tried the thing after entering the code gives : LEO_702

Comment: And my PC product name is 120-1020in do o also give my serial number?

Comment: To be clear you haven't just installed Ubuntu but are booting the Live USB?

Comment: ??? What do you mean? I installed it before then I deleted it and installed a older version on my drive buti have not installed it fully because I want it to be fixed first I’m not a doofus

Comment: I couldn't find anything about BIOS updates at support.hp.com for your HP Omni 120-1020in. Do you have Windows installed? Is there an app called `HP Support Assistant`, or similar there?

Comment: IDK there is 1 with windows know more app

Answer (score 1):

From this Bug Report (You should read the entire bug report from start to finish):

- [Intel 8550U with 620UHD GPU screen flashing](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/166)

This solution:

- Add kernel parameter: `drm.debug=0x1e log_buf_len=4M`

To add a kernel parameter use `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` and locate the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash drm.debug=0x1e log_buf_len=4M"
```

Save the file and exit `gedit` then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now reboot and see if the flickering is gone.

---

In my own `/etc/default/grub` file I keep random notes I've collected over the years about kernel parameters. I've extracted these old notes that may help you:

`# i915.enable_rc6=0 Fix screen flickering Kernel's > 4.12` https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=211399

`# i915.enable_psr=0 screen flickering kernel's > 4.6` https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics#Skylake_support

Comment: Okk I hope this will work thank you for typing so long stuff

Comment: @MadhavGarg I hope it works too. Let me know how it works out after you try it.