# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS flickering screen

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, nvidia, display, flicker

I just installed a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 on my Lenovo Z580 laptop and it’s dual boot with Windows 10.

Windows 10 runs fine, but whenever I launch Ubuntu, my PC screen starts flashing continuously. The flashing screen starts from the GRUB screen and continues to when I login into Ubuntu.

I searched and tested many different solutions but nothing changed. Here are some of the solutions I tried:

- Changing *NVIDIA (Performance mode)* into *NVIDIA On-Demand* (nvidia x-server config).
- Changing *NVIDIA (performance mode)* into *Intel (Power Saving mode)*.
- Setting `nomodeset` in GRUB config.
- Using proprietary NVIDIA drivers.
- Reinstalling the drivers from main server.
- Changing GRUB config to:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash drm.debug=0x1e log_buf_len=4M"
  ```
- ...

Can anyone help me on this problem?

Here are some links which didn't give me any good news:

- [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Screen Refresh / Flickering Issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241813/ubuntu-20-04-lts-screen-refresh-flickering-issue)
- [Ubuntu screen flickering](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231441/ubuntu-screen-flickering)
- [Whenever I launch Ubuntu my screen of PC starts flashing continuously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250305/whenever-i-launch-ubuntu-my-screen-of-pc-starts-flashing-continuously)
- https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/t/screen-glitching-problem-with-20-04/3661

Comment: I just bought a Lenovo E15 Thinkpad and installed Ubuntu 20.04 dual-boot with Windows 10. I'm seeing frequent screen flicker-to-black too. Did you ever solve it? Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan The OP solved it by downgrading the kernel to another version, as you can see in their answer.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog Thanks for the notification since I wouldn't have seen this update otherwise.

Comment: @Ryan No problem! If you want to get updates on a question (i.e. if it receives a new answer), you can also [*bookmark*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-question-bookmarks-work) it by clicking the bookmark icon next to it (right below the votes counter). Similarly, if you want to get notified of any updates on a question or answer, you can click the [*Follow*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345169/620527) option right beneath the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved by down-grading the ubuntu kernel

Comment: Downgrading *from* what version, *to* what version?

Comment: Yeah, can you share the details?